# Keyboard Shortcut to Deselect Omnibox in Chrome ?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

OS X user here. I'm currently learning both Vim and Vimium, it's been really fun. A major annoyance with Chrome is that I can press `Cmd+L` to highlight the address bar, but I can't unselect it without clicking on anywhere on the page (and resume to normal navigation). How do I (using the keyboard only) unselect the address bar in Chrome?

P.S. Sorry if this has been asked already. I just cannot find the combination of search terms in Google as what I'm searching for is a bit descriptive

Answer (score 11):

I am not a OS X user, but I think this should be the same as in Windows,press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> once or more time after selecting the Chrome address bar with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. In Windows pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> once or more times will deselect the omnibox in chrome, but I don't know if this will work also in OS X, it is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks @Devid. Yup, that works as a workaround. When I try here in SuperUser though, when I press `Tab`, it selects the next HTML element or something. So when I attempt to scroll using `j` on Vimium, an error beep occurs. I can press `j` again, and I end up in the SuperUser search box. From there I can unselect it and navigate using keyboard. I would much rather that I just plain unselect the address bar with no side effects such as selecting HTML elements.

Comment: In windows there is also F6 and pressing it 3 times deselects the omnibox without side effects. Maybe there is something similar in OS X

Comment: Best answer!!!!

Comment: @DaryllSantos If this answer worked for you (it did for me) you can select it as your answer.

Answer (score 10):

I've had the same issue but I found a simple hack. Just go to your Chrome settings and click manage search engines. Then add a new search engine with 'javascript:' as the url, and whatever word or key you want for the shortcut. I use Vim with jj or kk mapped to esc, so I used those two keys as the shortcut for my Chrome.

[image: http://imgur.com/ipIdKUV]

Comment: Two problems: can't set the custom engine as default. Two: how do you map a key-combo to escape? Just `map jj <Esc>`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are presumably a superuser in addition to using OS X, here is my [Karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner) `.xml` that enables me to exit the `omnibox` with `Command_L` + `; (ø on Norw/Danish keyboards)`. Change to whatever keycombo you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>

    <appendix>Use ø (;) to exit the satanically moronic omnibox in chrome.</appendix>
    <identifier>private.make_up_for_shitty_chrome_behavior</identifier>
    <only>GOOGLE_CHROME</only>

    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::SEMICOLON, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,

      __{ KeyCode::TAB, KeyCode::TAB, KeyCode::ESCAPE, }__
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

What it does is execute the key-sequence `TAB TAB ESC` when you trigger it. This makes the first HTML element selected so it is kind of a hack.

I'd personally just remap `ESC` to `ESC ESC` in Karabiner so that `ESC` drops out of the omnibox, but that might interfere with your usage/lead to uninteded consequences.

(I could not get Wang's answer to work)

Edit: This seems like a more robust way to do it in karabiner:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Mouse Warping</name>
    <vkopenurldef>
      <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SHELL_mousetowindowcenter</name>
      <url type="shell">
        <![CDATA[
                 /Applications/Karabiner.app/Contents/Library/utilities/bin/warp-mouse-cursor-position screen 0 bottom 0 right 0
        ]]>
      </url>
    </vkopenurldef>
    <item>
      <identifier>private.f14_mousetowindowcenter</identifier>
      <name>F14 to move the mouse to the center of the current window</name>
      <autogen>
        __SimultaneousKeyPresses__
        KeyCode::A, KeyCode::K,
        KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SHELL_mousetowindowcenter,
        KeyCode::VK_WAIT_100MS,
        PointingButton::LEFT,
        KeyCode::ESCAPE,
      </autogen>
    </item>
  </item>
  </root>
```

My first answer works for most sites, but for sites with many search boxes you need more than x tab clicks.

The code immediately above moves your cursor to the bottom left (i.e. edge of chrome window) and presses the left mouse-key once, selecting the window without any side-effects. This deselects the omnibox. I use `A+K` (home row, baby!) simultaneously to do this, but you will probably want to choose your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY don't want to use the `trackpad` or have no mouse

- [How to leave focus from address bar without mouse or trackpad](http://xavierchow.github.io/2016/03/07/vimium-leave-address-bar/)

  - We can press the trackpad to leave the address bar (when the mouse is at browser area, usually it's)
  - I avoid to use trackpad as possible as I can as my fingers hurt when use trackpad.
  - Luckily, we can add a custom search engine like below at chrome://settings/searchEngines.
  - Then we can type l then enter to go back to the browser area.

Check [here for more Chrome tips and tricks](https://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2018/06/awesome-tips-about-chrome.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are several Vimium feature requests for this BTW with the intention of enabling that for ESC, but the devs said there is no available API:

- https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/78
- https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/226
- https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/295
- https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/840

So I just use the Tab workaround mentioned at https://superuser.com/a/726451/128124 for now.